# Subquery returns more than one row even with MAX function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have searched and couldn't find anything that helped me in this case. The DB is MS SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have a complex query that I'm actually using CTE's for, where one of the subqueries should return one row for each column. However, I can't figure out how to do that.

Here's the code.

```
select MemberFK as LMFK, ContractNr, Contractbegin as LC, ContractEnd as LCE from Contracts as V 
WHERE 
MainContract=1
AND Description not like '%Mitarbeiter%'
AND Description not like '%Kind%'
AND Description not like '%Teen%'
AND Description not like '%Kid%'
AND Contractbegin = 
(select TOP 1 MAX(V1.Contractbegin) from Contracts as V1 WHERE 
(V1.Description like '%Gold%'
OR V1.Description like '%Silber%'
OR V1.Description like '%Bronze%'
OR V1.Description like '%Executive%' )
AND V1.ContractEnd>V1.Contractbegin --to flush out some erroneous rows
AND V1.MemberFK =V.MemberFK)
```

Sample problematic rows:

```
LMFK    ContractNr  LC  LCE
649 644 2002-10-01 00:00:00 2008-04-30 00:00:00
755 646 2002-11-01 00:00:00 2002-11-01 00:00:00
755 647 2002-11-01 00:00:00 2008-07-31 00:00:00
754 648 2002-11-01 00:00:00 2008-07-31 00:00:00
```

What I would like to do to get only one row per LMFK is to get the max ContractNr that satisfies the other conditions. As you can see, ContractNr 646 is not valid whereas 647 is. Looks like the `V1.ContractEnd>V1.Contractbegin` condition isn't working well.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: select V1.Contractbegin from Contracts as V1 WHERE 
(V1.Description like '%Gold%'
OR V1.Description like '%Silber%'
OR V1.Description like '%Bronze%'
OR V1.Description like '%Executive%' ORDER BY V1.Contractbegin DESC.  .... IF you run this you will probably see more than one row sharing the highest V1.ContractsBegin.

Comment: Also you have a typo, it says "Silber" instead of "Silver.

Comment: selecting top n without an order by clause seems like a good way to look for trouble.

Comment: But V1.ContractEnd>V1.Contractbegin is a condition the Contractbegin = ().  V1.ContractEnd>V1.Contractbegin is not a condition of main query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use ContractNr in the where cluse. Your query returns all records matched max Contractbegin

```
select MemberFK as LMFK, ContractNr, Contractbegin as LC, ContractEnd as LCE from Contracts as V 
WHERE 
MainContract=1
AND Description not like '%Mitarbeiter%'
AND Description not like '%Kind%'
AND Description not like '%Teen%'
AND Description not like '%Kid%'
AND ContractNr = 
(select TOP 1 MAX(V1.ContractNr) from Contracts as V1 WHERE 
(V1.Description like '%Gold%'
OR V1.Description like '%Silber%'
OR V1.Description like '%Bronze%'
OR V1.Description like '%Executive%' )
AND V1.ContractEnd>V1.Contractbegin --to flush out some erroneous rows
AND V1.MemberFK =V.MemberFK)
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying this. It seems to work better to select the max ContractNr. However, there is no condition for Contractbegin anymore. Is it not needed with the ContractNr clause? I wanted to get the latest contract in the system for every Member, and I I should get the maximum Contractbegin date for that.

Answer (score 0):

I always like creating a toy table and/or database to show off my ideas.  Below is one such snippet.

Here are some comments about your solution versus mine.

1 - When you compare a column to a pattern using a wild card at the beginning, the query optimizer is unable to use any indexes.  Therefore, this results in a full table scan.

2 - I always like testing for nulls.  The coalesce is a great way to have a null string default to an empty string.

3 - If you use a persisted computed column for your where logic, it is stored in the database when the record is inserted or updated.

4 - A persisted computed column can have a index, therefore, eliminates the table scan with larger tables.

I had to use a query index hint since for small tables, a table scan is faster.

Also, you might want to add member_fk and/or begin_date.  IE - more work / testing for a real life example.

5 - Last but not least, use window partitioning and the row_number() function to find the the latest row.

I bundled this into a CTE since you can not reference the calculation in the SELECT part of the statement in the WHERE clause.

There are some good concepts here:

- wild card pattern searching equals full table scan
- alwaystest/account for nulls
- persisted computed columns as an index
  for speed
- using grouping functions for pick top result

If you have any questions, just holler.

Sincerely

John

```
-- Drop old table
if object_id('tempdb.dbo.contracts') > 0
  drop table tempdb.dbo.contracts;
go

-- Create new table
create table tempdb.dbo.contracts
(
  id_num int identity(1,1),
  member_fk int,
  main_flag bit,
  begin_date smalldatetime,
  end_date smalldatetime,
  description_txt varchar(512),

  do_not_use_flag as
  (
    -- must have these words
    ( 
      case
        when lower(coalesce(description_txt, '')) like '%gold%' then 0
        when lower(coalesce(description_txt, '')) like '%silver%' then 0
        when lower(coalesce(description_txt, '')) like '%bronze%' then 0
        when lower(coalesce(description_txt, '')) like '%executive%' then 0
        else 1
      end
    ) 

    +

    -- must not have these words
    ( 
      case
        when lower(coalesce(description_txt, '')) like '%mitarbeiter%' then 1
        when lower(coalesce(description_txt, '')) like '%kind%' then 1
        when lower(coalesce(description_txt, '')) like '%teen%' then 1
        when lower(coalesce(description_txt, '')) like '%kid%' then 1
        else 0
      end
    ) 

    +

    -- must have begin_date <= end_date
    ( 
      case
        when begin_date is null then 1
        when end_date is null then 0
        when begin_date <= end_date then 0
        else 1
      end
    )

    + 
    (
      -- toss out non-main records
      case
        when main_flag = 1 then 0
        else 1
      end
    )
  ) persisted

);
go

-- add index on id include flag
create nonclustered index ix_contracts
    on tempdb.dbo.contracts (do_not_use_flag);
go

-- add data to table
insert into tempdb.dbo.contracts (member_fk, main_flag, begin_date, end_date, description_txt) 
values

-- shows up
(1, 1, getdate() - 5, getdate(), 'Silver - good contract for DBA'),

-- main contract <> 1
(1, 0, getdate() - 5, getdate(), 'Gold - good contract for DBA'),

-- no flag = true
(1, 1, getdate() - 5, getdate(), 'Bronze - good contract for Teen'),

-- end < begin
(1, 1, getdate(), getdate()-5, 'Bronze - good contract for DBA'),

(2, 1, getdate() - 5, getdate(), 'Executive - good contract for DBA');
go

-- wait 5 seconds
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:02';
go

insert into tempdb.dbo.contracts (member_fk, main_flag, begin_date, end_date, description_txt) 
values
(2, 1, getdate() - 4, getdate(), 'Executive - good contract for DBA');
go


-- show the raw data
select * from tempdb.dbo.contracts as c
go

-- show the data
;
with cte_contract_by_recent_begin_dte
as
(
  select 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY member_fk ORDER BY begin_date desc) as top_id, 
    *
  from 
    tempdb.dbo.contracts as c with(index(ix_contracts))
  where 
    c.do_not_use_flag = 0 
)
select * from cte_contract_by_recent_begin_dte as cte where cte.top_id = 1
```